# ESP32 (Arduino Core): "while(true)" loop in setup function

Tags: arduino, esp32

just a short question actually but I could not find any information on that: Is it ok to not use Arduinos `loop` function, and rather have a `while(true)` loop executing in the `setup` function?

I'm asking because I like to have class that deals with WiFi configuration. It reads WiFi connection data from preferences and if it cannot connect (due to lack of preferences or because the configured AP is not reachable) it should open an access point, wait for configuration (via webserver) and then reboot.

But I don't want the execution pointer to reach the actual `loop` when WiFi connection must be configured. The actual `loop` is only for normal operation. Thus, I created the `while(true)` loop in that WiFi configuration class. It seems to work, but are there possibly any consequences that I should be aware of? Or is basically ok to do it this way?

As a note: I do use `delay()` calls (or `yield()` calls) in that `while(true)` loop.

Thank you!

Comment: the WiFiManager library does what you describe in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code. You can do whatever you want. Waiting for connections in setup() is absolutely ok and quite common practice.

As you can see in Arduino's main() implementation: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp

```
int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing to consider is that you cannot use SerialEvent

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent

> SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the hardware serial
>   RX. This   routine is run between each time loop() runs

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot. Unfortunately, I'm using the ESP32. But thanks to your comment, i found their `main` entry point. Unfortunately, I think I might get problems with that watchdog timer: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2f249edb8e2627421be87c43167a187e55ed7db7/cores/esp32/main.cpp#L17

EDIT: Oops. Should have read the entire code. It appears that it's always false isn't it? What's the point of it? 

Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @timothy3001 You are referring to  loopTaskWDTEnabled as being always false?  I think that variable is set to false initially but can be changed in setup or loop

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm talking about. And yeah, thought so. I think I have also stumbled across functions to enable Watchdog a while ago.Thank you!